# Clone only a subfolder in repository

Tags: git

I wish to clone a repository onto my local machine which has the following structure:

```
project
├── folder1
├── folder2
├── file1
└── file2
```

file1 and file2 are huge and it is taking me forever to check them out. I'm not interested in writing to the repository, I only want to access some files in folder1 in a once-off, read-only manner.

Comment: If file1 and file2 are both binary files, they shouldn't be in your git repo.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/2235132) answer might help.

Comment: @RyPeck: where should they be, if not in Git?  Personally I'd suggest storing them in a *separate* repo containing only large files that are not always needed.

Comment: @JohnZwinck All depends on what they are, what his environment is like, how often they change, how necessary they are, how they are generated and his process... Can't suggest anything further without knowing more. Dropbox, Amazon, or a network share are possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible using Git.